# In pandas, how to set a index with the combine of multi columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
         InvoiceID PayerAccountId  ... user:Project user:Purpose
0        314758801   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
1        314758801   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
2        314758801   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
3        314758801   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
4        314758801   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
...            ...            ...  ...          ...          ...
1726119        NaN   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
1726120        NaN   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
1726121        NaN   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
1726122        NaN   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN
1726123        NaN   123456789012  ...          NaN          NaN

[1726124 rows x 27 columns]
```

And it's info is here:

```
[1726124 rows x 27 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1726124 entries, 0 to 1726123
Data columns (total 27 columns):
InvoiceID                        object
PayerAccountId                   object
LinkedAccountId                  object
RecordType                       object
ProductName                      object
RateId                           object
SubscriptionId                   object
UsageType                        object
Operation                        object
AvailabilityZone                 object
ReservedInstance                 object
ItemDescription                  object
UsageStartDate                   datetime64[ns]
UsageEndDate                     datetime64[ns]
UsageQuantity                    float64
BlendedRate                      float64
BlendedCost                      float64
UnBlendedRate                    float64
UnBlendedCost                    float64
ResourceId                       object
aws:cloudformation:stack-name    object
user:Cost                        object
user:CostNo                      object
user:Dept                        object
user:Name                        object
user:Project                     object
user:Purpose                     object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(5), object(20)
memory usage: 355.6+ MB
```

I want to set a index with the columns which is **`object`** type:

```
Index(['InvoiceID', 'PayerAccountId', 'LinkedAccountId', 'RecordType',
       'ProductName', 'RateId', 'SubscriptionId', 'UsageType', 'Operation',
       'AvailabilityZone', 'ReservedInstance', 'ItemDescription', 'ResourceId',
       'aws:cloudformation:stack-name', 'user:Cost', 'user:CostNo',
       'user:Dept', 'user:Name', 'user:Project', 'user:Purpose'],
      dtype='object')
```

Then I want to get the *sum* of the **`float`** type, *sum* of the `UsageEndDate - UsageStartDate`, how to reach that? Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for @Joshua Maerker 's help. Your code inspired me. So, the final solution is here:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Define the columns data type
data_type = {
    "UsageStartDate": "datetime64[ns]",
    "UsageEndDate": "datetime64[ns]",
    "UsageQuantity": np.float,
    "BlendedRate": np.float,
    "BlendedCost": np.float,
    "UnBlendedRate": np.float,
    "UnBlendedCost": np.float
}

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=np.object)

# Drop the useless columns
list_drop = ["RecordId", "PricingPlanId"]
df.drop(columns=list_drop, inplace=True)

# Change the type of some column
for k, v in data_type.items():
    df[k] = df[k].astype(v)

# Get the unique attributes
df1 = df.drop(columns=list(data_type.keys())).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# Add the auxiliary column
df["Auxiliary"] = df[df1.columns].apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
df1["Auxiliary"] = df1[df1.columns].apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

# Add the duration column
df["Duration"] = df["UsageEndDate"] - df["UsageStartDate"]

# Structure the rules for grouped to apply
agg = {
    "UsageQuantity": "sum",
    "Duration": "sum",
    "BlendedCost": "sum",
    "UnBlendedCost": "sum",
}

# Get the result
result = df.groupby("Auxiliary", sort=False).agg(agg)

# Combine the result
cleaned = pd.merge(df1, result, how="inner", on="Auxiliary")

# Drop auxiliary column
df = cleaned.drop(columns="Auxiliary")

# Transfer the result into mysql database
df.to_sql(name="cleaned_result", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

BTW, the func of yours to create auxiliary column **NOT** work for me, maybe it caused by there are some `Nan` in my rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# select all columns with object Type
dtypOpj = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])

# create a new column 
df['indexstring'] = ""

# iterate over all Columns with object Type
for column in dtypOpj.columns:
    df['indexstring'] = df['indexstring'] + df[column] 

# Set new Column as Index
df = df.set_index('indexstring')

# select all float types
dtypFloat = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'float32'])

# sum of all Float Columns
sumFloats = df[dtypFloat.columns].sum()

# sum of UsageEndDate - UsageStartDate
df['sumDifference'] = df["UsageEndDate"] - df["UsageStartDate"]
df['sumDifference'].sum()
```